# como comparar en un if la propiedad none que viene del CSS con Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Cordial saludo.

Estoy aprendiendo a modificar el CSS desde Jquery, tengo un objeto del siguiente tipo:

```
let _displayNavbarDesk = $('#navbarNavDropdown').css("display");
```

Puede ser: flex, block, none

Lo que yo quiero es hacer un condicional cuando la propiedad display sea none se ejecute el codigo ya intenté con new String($('#navbarNavDropdown').css("display")); pero no consigo lograrlo.

```
if(_displayNavbarDesk === "none"){
    //Hacer algo
}
```

Alguien me puede decir con que objeto especifico none debo de comparar para que el condicional se cumpla? un objeto como del tipo Jquery.None() ???

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé que como tienes el HTML en tu código, pero tu JS es correcto. A través de la función `css()` puedes obtener el estado de la regla CSS `display`, tanto si el elemento lo está obteniendo a través del atributo `style`, como si lo está obteniendo a través de CSS (por su ID, clase, etiqueta, etc).

```js
const displayNoneEnStyle = $('#displayNoneEnStyle').css('display')
const displayNoneEnCSS = $('#displayNoneEnCSS').css('display')

if (displayNoneEnStyle === 'none') {
  console.log('Se detecta display none en el atributo style')
}
else {
  console.log('NO se detecta display none en el atributo style')
}

if (displayNoneEnCSS === 'none') {
  console.log('Se detecta display none en el CSS')
}
else {
  console.log('NO se detecta display none en el CSS')
}
```

```css
#displayNoneEnCSS {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="displayNoneEnStyle" style="display: none"></div>
<div id="displayNoneEnCSS"></div>
```